# iPad UIPopoverController crashes with UIImagePicker, no ARC

Tags: objective-c, ipad, crash, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a button that is supposed to create a popover with a UIImagePickerController, instead it crashes. I'm not using ARC, and I have looked through many other entries and no others helped. I'm not prematurely releasing anything. Does anyone have a fix?

```
-(void)pickImageAction {

    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {

        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [popoverController release];

    } else {

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

            picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
            popoverController.delegate = self;
                        //Crashes here
            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(300, 300, 320, 480) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];



        }

    }


}    

-(IBAction)buttonClicked {

[self pickImageAction];

}
```

Comment: can you show where it does crash?

Comment: @Julien it makes it up to     [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(237, 333, 320, 480) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES]; then crashes

Comment: let me reformulate: can we see the crash stack trace?

Comment: @Julien here is the stack:  *** First throw call stack:
(0x1f71552 0x13a4e7e 0x1f7132b 0x120b91 0x120bbd 0x1211fc 0x11818f 0x129c20 0x80c8e 0x80a8d 0x80a8d 0x7c016 0x824de 0x7a91d 0x4fec4b 0xfc9b 0xfd5d 0x13b8705 0x37450 0x373e8 0xf7b21 0xf807f 0xf71e8 0x66e0f 0x67022 0x44eaa 0x36828 0x1ecce39 0x1eccb10 0x1ee71b5 0x1ee6f22 0x1f18176 0x1f17504 0x1f173db 0x1ecb823 0x1ecb6a8 0x3418c 0x2792 0x26c5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: better… this means that there is an uncaught exception being throwed. It should have been logged just before the crash. What is this exception?

Comment: 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'